Get PID of command in one line bash script
When trying to get the PID of a shell command, it is possible using a script file:
#!/bin/bash

ls -lha &
echo "$!"

However, it is not possible using only the terminal.
/bin/bash -c 'ls -lha & ; echo "$!"'
This returns the error:

/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

The manual states the following:

A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines
separated by one of the operators ;, &, &&, or ||,
and optionally terminated by one of ;, &, or <newline>. 
Of these list operators, && and || have equal precedence,
followed by ; and &, which have equal precedence.
A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a list
instead of a semicolon to delimit commands.
If a command is terminated by the control operator &,
the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. 
The shell does not wait for the command to finish,
and the return status is 0. 
Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially;
the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn. 
The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.

So I also tried using newline, but was not able to use it:
/bin/bash -c 'ls -lha & \n echo "$!"'
How can I call a shell command to run on background and get the PID?
P.S.: I will not use ls command and it is a more complex script. 
This is just a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Both ; and & are command separators. 
You need one to separate the ls command from the echo command,
but not both. 
Just leave out the ; and do
/bin/bash -c 'ls -lha & echo "$!"'

If you want, you can add an actual newline:
/bin/bash -c 'ls -lha &
echo "$!"'

or use $'…':
/bin/bash -c $'ls -lha & \n echo "$!"'

Of course, you need to have command separators between commands;
one between every two consecutive commands. 
So, if you want to have, let’s say, four commands,
where the first is asynchronous and the rest are synchronous, you would use
             command1 & command2; command3; command4
